# Ternary operator: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to map an array of typescript interface objects and print its values in a table. My array looks something like this:

```
export interface data {
                fields?: field[];
            }

export interface field {
                name: string;
                description: string;
                subfields: subfield[];
            }
```

But I want to print only that `field` which has `field.name` equal to `requiredName`

On usage of ternary operator to define condition I am getting the following error:
`Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression`

I would appreciate some help in defining conditional statements to map my object. I have used ternary operator before too but only for printing value in a table cell instead of dynamically creating one.

Here´s my code so far:

```
           <Table>
            <TableBody>
              <TableRow >
                <TableCell>
                {props.fields.map((it) =>
                  {it.name===requiredName ? (
                    <Table>...</Table>
                  ) : (
                    null
                  )}
                )} 
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried with a return in front of the ternary?

Comment: You do not return anything, that is the error

Comment: ```export interface data {
                fields?: field[];
            }```  isn't the ternary syntax wrong here ? ?

Comment: @jarivak that is not a ternary https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#optional-properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the return statement in front of your ternary operator.

It should be:

```
return it.name===requiredName ? (
                    <Table>...</Table>
                  ) : (
                    null
                  )
```

Comment: Did that fix your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have curly brackets in your arrow function, and therefore your ternary operator is executed as statement in the function body, but not returned.

This is what you currently have: (I just added the implicit `return undefined` to the function body.)

```
<TableCell>
  {props.fields.map((it) => {
    it.name===requiredName ? (<Table>...</Table>) : (null)
    return undefined
    }
  )} 
</TableCell>
```

The result of you map function is therefore an array with only `undefined` values in there.

You probably meant to do this (Note the absent curly brackets, which cause the arrow function to return the value of the ternary):

```
<TableCell>
  {props.fields.map((it) => 
    it.name===requiredName ? (<Table>...</Table>) : (null)
  )} 
</TableCell>
```